# Regex: set capture to fixed string

Tags: regex, regex-group

I want to match the string `a` but I want my capture patten to be `b`.

To capture `a` named as `id` I can easily do:

```
(?<id>a)
```

but I want `id` to be `b` when the original string was just `a`. i.e I want the capture to be characters that aren't in the original string.

For example, in PHP it would look something like:

```
preg_match('/your_magic/', 'a', $matches);
print $matches['id'] == 'b'; // true
```

Comment: Google `regex substitution <name of your programming language>` and you'll find many examples

Comment: are you trying to use a variable in a regex pattern? does this question make sense to anyone?

Comment: @sgroves I updated the question, is that better?

Comment: @alfasin I know how to use regexes. I'm not trying to replace one string with another. I want the captured characters to not exist in the original string.

Comment: ahhh. never heard of anything like this. what's wrong examining the matched string and using an `if` statement to modify it?

Comment: " want the captured characters to not exist in the original string" - but they DO exist... sorry but your question is still not clear. Maybe you should try http://sscce.org/ ?

Comment: @sgroves I'm in a framework that uses the captured pattern named "id"

Comment: @alfasin my input string is `a`. I want `b` to be captured. It does not exist in the input string.

Comment: @PaulTarjan repeating what you already said doesn't make it any clearer. I think that you should clarify what do you mean by `captured` - you can't capture something that doesn't exist.

Comment: @alfasin where does the character `b` exist in my input string?

Comment: @PaulTarjan `c`also doesn't exist - should we `capture` the letter `c` as well ? further, after we captured it - what should we do with it ?

Comment: @alfasin I updated the question with some code, does that help?

Comment: my attempt to explain this - he wants to match a pattern, e.g. `a`, but have the matched string returned as something *different*, e.g. `'b'` - sort of like a substitution within the match performed at run time. he doesn't want to modify the original string. (unfortunately i don't think this is possible)

Comment: @sgroves now it makes much more sense and now I also understand your first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get anything in to a capturing group which isn't in the input string. Capturing groups are (at least in Perl) partially represented as start/end positions of the original input string.

If the value you want the capturing group to get is in the input string you can do that using lookarounds. The desired string has to be after the match if your regex flavor has a limited lookbehind (like PHP).

For example:

```
preg_match('/a(?=.*(?<id>b))/', 'a foo b', $matches);
print "matched '$matches[0]', id is '$matches[id]'";
```

Output:

```
matched 'a', id is 'b'
```